# python does not read the first and the last files from a sub-directory (last file sometimes, first files always)

Tags: python-3.x

this is the code i am using:

```
for i in article_list:
    f = open(i)
    first_line = f.readline().strip().split()
    for j, line in enumerate(f):
        if j == 0:
            date_article = word_tokenize(line)
        if j >= 3:
            lines = lines + " " + line
    f.close()
    word = word_tokenize(lines)
    lines = ""
```

after which i am supposed to do some stuff with my word[ ] list and so on...
the reason i am emptying the lines is so that each time i do stuff with the word[ ], i am clearing that as well...

Now my article_list contains the exact path of all the .txt files i am supposed to be using(reading).
I have a structure like the following:

```
-Folder A    (example Main_Folder)
--Folder 1    (example: 2015-01-01)
---file1.txt    (example: 99628.txt)
---file2.txt    (example: 99629.txt)
---file3.txt    (example: 99630.txt)
--Folder 2    (example: 2015-01-02)
---file4.txt    (example: 99631.txt)
---file5.txt
```

and so on

Now upon reading, the first folder contains only one txt file and it is being read.
But other folders have multiple .txt files, and none of them have the first file being read.
My sub folders are all dates like 2015-01-01 etc. and all my files are numeric like 99621.txt1
By first and last files in directory, i meant the folder 1, folder 2 etc... folder

an example of a file would be something like:

```
ABCD DEFG GGHI
2015-01-01
Report by John Doe
Report starts...
Multiple lines of report
Report Ends
```

Here it is **IMPORTANT** to note that the first_line is being read in each file... , i.e. the first_line in my code does indeed return ABCD DEFG GGHI.
Also another problem is that eventhough the first line is ABCD DEFG GGHI, when i use the enumerate function with j, line
and i take j == 0 as shown in my code, the date is being read... but i wanted it, and eventhough it is broken as per the code, it works so i dont want a fix there unless it is affecting the rest...

similarly with the rest of the file (i imagine because i read one line from f and then enumerating the rest).

**Main Problem**:

Now however, in the first file of a folder (other than the first folder), the contents of the report are not being read... both lines and word[ ] return empty in the first file.
the Date, however is **STILL BEING READ** with j==0

If you can replicate the problem, kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

nevermind... some files had an empty line for my report by person line... and since there was no \n being read there,  if j>=3 was started, it read it all as empty